# Centre and axes of symmetry for quadrics

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, quadrics

Since it is very hard to find good and organized scripts online for quadrics I came here to maybe find some answers to questions that've been bugging me lately:

1. If a quadric has two axes of symmetry, are they always perpendicular?
2. Is the intersection of two axis of symmetry always a centre of the quadric?
3. If 1. and 2. are false, can we make 2. correct if we assume the two axes to be perpendicular?

Answer (score 0):

1. If there were two axis not perpendicular, by reflection there would be more than two axis.
2. If an axis was not by the center, there would be two centers.

---

Note that by a similarity transformation (which preserves axis and center), a centered conic can be reduced to

$$\lambda x^2+\mu y^2=1.$$

In this representation the symmetry axis are obviously $x=0$ and $y=0$, which are orthogonal and meet at the origin. This generalizes to quadrics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So every quadric has either 1 or 2 axes of symmetry and exactly 1 centre? And if the quadric has 2 axes of symmetry they must be perpendicular. Did I pick that up correctly?

Comment: @Buh: parabolas have no center.

Comment: Okay, so let me try to rephrase it. Every quadric as either 1 or 2 axes of symmetry. If it has 2 axes then they must be perpendicular and the quadric has exactly one centre.